# (Python) List index out of range

Tags: python, list, indexing

So, in a Tic-Tac-Toe game I was developing I decided to make the AI a random number, as a joke. Here are the specifics:

```
  board = []
def createboard():
    board.append(['_',' ','_',' ','_'])
    board.append(['_',' ','_',' ','_'])
    board.append(['_',' ','_',' ','_'])
...
while bot_move_val == False or bot_move_made == False:

        bot_move_row = 0
        bot_move_col = 0

        bot_move_row_rand = randint(0,3) 
        bot_move_col_rand = randint(0,3)

        if bot_move_row_rand == 1:
            bot_move_row = 0
            bot_move_made = True
        elif bot_move_row_rand == 2:
            bot_move_row = 2
            bot_move_made = True
        elif bot_move_row_rand == 3:
            bot_move_row = 4
            bot_move_made = True

        if bot_move_col_rand == 1:
            bot_move_col = 0
            bot_move_made = True
        elif bot_move_col_rand == 2:
            bot_move_col = 2
            bot_move_made = True
        elif bot_move_col_rand == 3:
            bot_move_col = 4
            bot_move_made = True


        if bot_move_row > 4 or bot_move_row < 0 or bot_move_col > 4 or bot_move_col < 0 or board[bot_move_row][bot_move_col] == 'X':
            break
        else:
            bot_move_val = True
```

The code generates this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\[DATA EXPUNGED]\gamestravaganza.py", line 250, in <module>
if bot_move_row > 4 or bot_move_row < 0 or bot_move_col > 4 or bot_move_col < 0 or board[bot_move_row][bot_move_col] == 'X':
IndexError: list index out of range
```

As far as I can tell, `bot_move_row` and `bot_move_col` are not in the list `board`, despite being at most as long as the list by definition.

Comment: shouldn't be `2` instead of `4` ?  you have 3 rows/columns: 0,  1, 2.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike some other places in Python  (like the `range` method), `random.randint(a,b)` includes the upper bound. So 3 is a possible outcome, and since the board list is zero-indexed, that would be out of range.

Or as [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint) put it :

> random.randint(a, b)
>        Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b.

So you should use `randint(0,2)`  instead.

Comment: Aww, I'm retarded. Now I have to change the whole thing.

Comment: Maybe start from scratch and try to improve on your original design. It's lacking elegance.

Answer (score 1):

You have only 3 rows.
The if condition should be

```
if bot_move_row > 2 or bot_move_row < 0 or bot_move_col > 4 or bot_move_col < 0 or board[bot_move_row][bot_move_col] == 'X':
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming at some point you call the function `createboard` to build your board then there are a few places that are causing difficulty.

The board you create has 3 rows and 5 columns, but you are translating both rows and columns in the same way (ie anticipating equal numbers of rows vs columns). I would keep them both the same at 3.

As stated elsewhere your calls to `randint` select from a range with 4 numbers (0, 1, 2, 3) as `randint` includes both endpoints.

Finally your if condition tests that values are within a range that you specify yourself, making it less clear what you are really testing for.

To get the same basic functionality as what you seem to intend above you could rewrite it as:

```
# Create your board
board = [['_','_','_'], ['_','_','_'], ['_','_','_']]

#Handle one move
def botMove():
    while False:
        # Attempt to choose a row/column
        row = randint(0, 2)
        column = randint(0, 2)
        if board[row][column] == '_':
            # Randomly selected row/column is Empty, mark it as the bots and return
            board[row][column] = 'X'
            break
```

This of course does not handle what happens when the board is full (*as written above it would loop indefinitely*). To flesh out the game you would need something to handle user input (presuming player vs computer) and something to determine winner/draw.